# ¿Cómo enviar los estilos Sass compilados con vue-cli (webpack-simple) a un archivo externo?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

### El problema:

En los componentes de **vue-cli** se encuentra la etiqueta `<style lang="scss">`. Esta se encarga de tomar todo lo que encierra y compilarlo a **CSS** mediante **Webpack**. Cuando el código en su interior es compilado, lo genera en una etiqueta `<style>` dentro del archivo **HTML** (en realidad lo genera en `build.js`, pero ya en el navegador queda como he dicho)...

Quisiera que en vez de compilarse dentro del **HTML** en la etiqueta `<style>` me lo compile en un archivo externo, como por ejemplo un `build.css`.

Comment: Y porque querrias hacer eso? tal vez podrias explicar la idea detras de esto?

Comment: La idea es no llenar todo el archivo HTML con los estilos de los componentes, ya que si tengo muchos se extenderá el HTML... Pienso en el rendimiento, o ¿crees que no afecte en nada?

Comment: no deberia. Los archivos estan minimizados por el compilador, y ademas no importa si el archivo es largo o son muchos archivos, ya que los necesita todos y los tiene que bajar todos. Y una app vue baja en general un solo archivo js que contiene todo lo que necesita.

Comment: Vale, te entiendo. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes segmentar tu estilo css en varios archivos directamente.

Por ejemplo, en el archivo **app.vue** ( o como se llame su .vue inicial ) puede añadir lo siguiente:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import './styles/build.css';
  // or
  @import './styles/build.scss';
</style>
```

Ahora en el directorio styles, el archivo **build** será importado:

```
.example1 {

}

.example2 {

}
```